# Typescript unable to assert the type of a concrete instance that inherits type

Tags: typescript

In the following example, I've created a concreate class `Dialog` that has a `TState` and `TResult`.  The problem is that when I pass it into the `show()` method that even though the `TResult` matches the `TResult` of the component type being passed in, the result is `Unknown` instead of `Boolean | undefined`.

```js
interface DialogBase<TState, _TResult> {
    dialogState: TState;
}

class Test {
    public show<TResult, TState>(
      component: { new(...args: any[]): DialogBase<TState, TResult> }, 
      state: TState): TResult | undefined {
        return;
    }
}

class State {}

class Dialog implements DialogBase<State, Boolean> {
    dialogState: State = new State();
}

const test = new Test();
test.show(Dialog, new State());  // return type Unknown
```

What am I missing to allow typescript to assert the return type of the show method as the typed TResult of the DialogBase?

I can even move the type of the component into the generic and it still fails to recognize the return type:

```js
interface DialogBase<TState, _TResult> {
    dialogState: TState;
}

class Test {
    public show<TResult, TState, TDialog extends DialogBase<TState, TResult>>(
      component: { new(...args: any[]): TDialog  }, 
      state: TState): TResult | undefined {
        return;
    }
}

class State {}

class Dialog implements DialogBase<State, Boolean> {
    dialogState: State = new State();
}

const test = new Test();
test.show(Dialog, new State());  // return type Unknown
```

Comment: It seems that without a concrete property that takes on the value, you cannot do this.

Comment: TS is unable to figure out your return type if you did not provide any tips for TS compiler

Comment: @captain-yossarian `TResult` of the method is the same `TResult` of the DialogBase.  If I pass in a DialogBase<State, Boolean>, why does it not recognize that TResult is a Boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can help TS figure that out by providing some hints?

```
interface DialogBase<TState, TResult> {
    dialogState: TState;
    isHidden: TResult;
}

class Test {
    public show<TResult, TState>(
      component: { new(...args: any[]): DialogBase<TState, TResult> }, 
      state: TState): TResult | undefined {
        return;
    }
}

class State {}

class Dialog implements DialogBase<State, Boolean> {
    dialogState: State = new State();
    isHidden = false;
}

const test = new Test();
test.show(Dialog, new State());
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it introduces a new one.  Now anyone creating a dialog has to create a property that's never used.  Not sure trading one for the other is valuable.

Comment: It's like it just *has to* have a property.  Even when I use `Omit<>` it still doesn't know.

Comment: I tried making the property optional `isHIdden?: TResult` and if you don't implement the property, it doesn't know, but if you do implement it, then it does... so weird.

Comment: If I changed `DialogBase` in your example, to an `abstract class` and `abstract dialogState` and set `isHidden: TResult | undefined` then other programmers can just ignore the `isHidden` property and not need to implement anything not actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

IT is more explanation than answer.
Please take a look on next example, it is identical to your:

```js
function foo<T>(arg: number): T | undefined {
    return 
}

/**
 * unknown - because TS is unable to figure out what type you are going to return
 */
const result = foo(42)
```

To help somehow TS compiler to figure out what type you are going to return, you should provide some restrictions for generic.

For example, you can do this:

```js
function foo<T extends Array<number>>(arg: number): T | undefined {
    return 
}

const result = foo(42) // number[] | undefined
```

In this case, TS knows that you are going to return either number[] or undefined.

You can even do more.

You can provide overloadings:

```js
function foo(arg:string):number;
function foo(arg:number):string;
function foo<T extends Array<number>>(arg: number|string): T | undefined {
    return 
}

const result = foo(42) // string
const result2 = foo('42') // number
```

Now, TS knows, that if you will provide `number`, you will receive `string` and vice-versa.

How it helps.

Comment: It's not the same, because the parameter passed in my example has the same generic type.  Your parameter is not generic so typescript cannot assert the type.

Comment: Your last example can be [Simplified by generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgIYBOA5gFyIYCUZGiA3gFCJOIECmUIBShRA3PQF969UJFgJEAI0IBGfMTJgQAW0msCFWkNHR4SaQQBM80ogDOUAjDBFNQ+hAQWWrMyAA2URAF5kqHAAshhSIAPShiEqq6g5OXmxunoY+fnA4AORB6SHh5pbWRMIGcgkeUBT8BsalnhX0xTg1UMGVhNWuZS3C9EA) as even thought the type is never explicitly set, typescript can assert the type in the simplified example.